# JSON epoch to date function brings back wrong date

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, epoch

When parsing the JSON, all variables are correct but when converting the epoch to a string like "The time is 19:06 PM, on Thursday, the 29th of December." it always outputs "The time is 8:06 AM, on Saturday, the 16th of January."

I've even tried inputting a direct epoch time into the function and still get this consistent response. I've not used javascript or jQuery or JSON before so sorry if it is a silly mistake.

I've posted my code up on jsFiddle so you can see what I mean. Any help is greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/7WLfq/23/

Comment: Script will no longer run as I had to remove my api key from it since it went over my usage agreements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript Unix time uses milliseconds:

```
epoch = parseInt(pj.current_observation.local_epoch)*1000
```

That should do it for you.  Worked for me!

Comment: I forgot about that, thanks a bunch! I get confused that PHP uses just seconds and javascript milliseconds, hopefully I'll remember now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to multiply those epoch dates by 1000. JavaScript dates are based on *millseconds* since the epoch, not seconds.

Note that it's saying 16 Jan 1970 :-)

Comment: I forgot to check what year it was outputting, I should probably check that the next time I get an error like this, thank you.